# How I can make react-d3-tooltip version(1.4.14) compatible with the react latest version(15.3.2)

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-d3

When I run the command

```
npm install react-d3-tooltip --save
```

it shows the following warning on the terminal like as in the attached image. Unmet peer dependency react@0.14.7.

[image]

My package.json file includes the following dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "6.17.0",
"babel-eslint": "7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "6.2.5",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-stage-1": "6.16.0",
"cheerio": "0.22.0",
"colors": "1.1.2",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
"css-loader": "0.25.0",
"eslint": "2.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "6.3.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
"file-loader": "0.9.0",
"jquery": "2.2.2",
"jsdom": "9.6.0",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"node-sass": "3.10.1",
"postcss-loader": "0.13.0",
"react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.5",
"redux-devtools": "3.3.1",
"redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "1.1.1",
"redux-devtools-log-monitor": "1.0.11",
"redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.4",
"redux-slider-monitor": "1.0.7",
"rimraf": "2.5.4",
"sass-loader": "4.0.2",
"style-loader": "0.13.1",
"url-loader": "0.5.7",
"webpack": "1.13.2",
"webpack-dashboard": "0.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2"
},
"dependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "6.5.0",
"classnames": "2.2.5",
"d3": "4.2.8",
"http-server": "0.9.0",
"lodash": "4.16.3",
"react": "15.3.2",
"react-bootstrap": "0.30.5",
"react-d3-tooltip": "1.4.14",
"react-dom": "15.3.2",
"react-intl": "2.1.5",
"react-redux": "4.4.5",
"react-router": "2.8.1",
"react-router-bootstrap": "0.23.1",
"redux": "3.6.0",
"redux-form": "6.1.0",
"redux-intl": "1.0.1",
"semantic-ui-react": "0.56.1"
 }
```

**How I can solve this unmet peer dependency**

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @Dani, I didn't get the solution. As the react-d3 repo is not maintaining, I started creating charts using d3 manually with reactjs.